# Log.d doesn't print out message

Tags: android, logging

I get an error  ***java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message*** when using Log statement with the following code

```
 for (Application app : mApplications) {
            Log.d("LOG", "********");
            Log.d("LOG", app.getName());
            Log.d("LOG", app.getArtist());
            Log.d("LOG", app.getReleaseDate());

        }
```

but in second parameter, If I add another string between quotes the error is gone

```
for(Application app: mApplications){
            Log.d("LOG", "******************");
            Log.d("LOG","Name: " +app.getName());
            Log.d("LOG","Artist: " +app.getArtist());
            Log.d("LOG","ReleaseDate: " +app.getReleaseDate());

        }
```

what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: log message cannot be null.. may be Application app null checkout?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you've concatenated a string with the a null variable.

`Log` needs a non-null message string.

Alternatively, this also works because it will print `"null"` but it doesn't look clean

```
Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(app.getName()));
Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(app.getArtist()));
Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(app.getReleaseDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using Log.d it is generally use for debugging and this is the correct syntax for Log.d `d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)` For better understanding [See this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

In your case First you are using this

```
for (Application app : mApplications) {
        Log.d("LOG", "********");
        Log.d("LOG", app.getName());
        Log.d("LOG", app.getArtist());
        Log.d("LOG", app.getReleaseDate());

    }
```

And generate this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` because you can't put message as per Log.d syntax rule.

I hope you understand...

Comment: Adding a Throwable isn't the more frequently used method

Comment: I know But error should be java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message So

Comment: I believe even with the Throwable, you still can't have a null message.